# Saving QgsRasterBlock object as .tif, or to add it as QgsRasterLayer?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am currently working on a qgis plugin and I need to simulate each pixel value in raster. I read that the best way to read each pixel value is by using **QgsRasterBlock**  object and I assigned simulated value to second QgsRasterBlock object object like this:

```
filename = "C:\Users\AB\Desktop\PyQgis\usa_dem\e10g.tif"
registry = QgsProviderRegistry.instance()
provider = registry.provider("gdal",filename)
QSettings().setValue("/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useGlobal")
stDev = 1 
raster_extent = provider.extent()
raster_width = provider.xSize()
raster_height = provider.ySize()
no_data_value = provider.srcNoDataValue(1)
block = provider.block(1,raster_extent,raster_width,raster_height)
block_2 = provider.block(1,raster_extent,raster_width,raster_height)
if block.isValid():
    for x in range(raster_width):
        for y in range(raster_height):
                        elevation = block.value(x,y)
                        if elevation == no_data_value:
                            print("no data")
                        else:
                            elevation_2 = random.uniform(elevation- 
                            stDev,elevation+stDev)
                            block_2.setValue(x,y,elevation_2)
```

I am new to PyQGIS and I want to know is this approach is good or not.

Comment: It sounds like you are seeking a [codereview.se]. What happens when you run the code that you have presented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can clone a `dataprovider` to save the `qgsRasterBlock` to a tif file as following:

```
layer=qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
provider=layer.dataProvider()

providerclone=provider.clone()

qgsRasterBlock=providerclone.block(1,layer.extent(),layer.width(),layer.height())
qgsRasterBlock.setValue(1100,350,155)  
providerclone.setEditable(1)  
providerclone.writeBlock(qgsRasterBlock5,1)  

filepath='D:/test.tif'

file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(filepath)

pipe = QgsRasterPipe()

pipe.set(providerclone)   

file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, provider.xSize(),provider.ySize(),provider.extent(),provider.crs())
```